# Remove anonymous link from SharePoint thanks to PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, access, script

I am currently working on a script that should remove an anonymous link from SharePoint using Powershell.
I don't know where to start and i would like to know if somebody has an idea on how to do it.

The goal of the script is that we should remove entirely a link, i know microsoft can remvove the access after a few day but the link still exists it is just expired. I would like to destroy this link in order to be able to create another one

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Sample PowerShell script to remove anonymous link for specific file.

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

    $username = "admin@xxx.onmicrosoft.com" 
    $password = "Password" 
    $url = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/lee"

    $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force 

    $clientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url) 
    $credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $securePassword) 
    $clientContext.Credentials = $credentials 

    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web]::DeleteAllAnonymousLinksForObject($clientContext, "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/lee/MyDoc2/testdata.xlsx")
    $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
    Write-Host "-----"
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, i am trying what you gave and i have the following error :

Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request." At C:\Users\XXXXXXXXXXXX\Desktop\Link.ps1:15 char:5 + $clientContext.ExecuteQuery() + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException

I don't understand why i have this can you explain it to me pliz

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hey thanks for your answer, i am trying what you gave and i have the following error :

Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."
At C:\Users\XXXXXXXXXXXX\Desktop\Link.ps1:15 char:5
+     $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException

I don't understand why i have this can you explain it to me pliz

Thanks in advance